# Permanently set the resolution for my second monitor

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, resolution

After every restart, I have to manually set the resolution of my second monitor with:

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-0 "1600x900_60.00"
```

Unity never picks up the resolution automatically, so is there a way to set this permanently so I don't need to do it every time?

Comment: why do you use sudo?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use `sudo` here, in fact you shouldn't if it is unnecessary.

Simply create a small script:

```
#!/bin/bash

xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 "1600x900_60.00"
```

- Copy it into an empty file, save it as `set_resolution.sh`
- Add it to your startup applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add the command:

  ```
  /bin/bash /path/to/set_resolution.sh
  ```

#### NB

You might have to add a small break to wait for the desktop to be fully loaded, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 10
xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 "1600x900_60.00"
```

Comment: @Roman does it work? Did you run into problems? Please let me know.

Comment: Jacob, you should know by now that a bunch of Rep1 users, post their question and never come back after they've got an answer!  :P  ;-) (upvote BTW: I would have said exactly the same)

Comment: @JacobVlijm, sorry for only coming back to you now... never saw your message.  It didnt't work for me, what I ended up doing is creating a script `resolution.py` and running the commands using 
`os.system('xrandr --newmode ...ect')` and executing that script on startup.

Comment: @Roman Wheter you do it from python or bash should do *exactly* the same. If you do it with python, I'd strongly suggest using `subprocess.Popen` instead of `os.system()`