# How to permanently set my second screen's resolution?

Tags: drivers, screen, startup, xrandr, display-resolution

For the past few days, I've been trying to match my second screen's resolution to my match my main screen.

Using the following code i got from this website, I was to get it done:

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 1368x768_60.00
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode  1368x768_60.00
```

My problem, now, is when i reboot my computer, the second screen goes back to its old resolution. Then, i learned that i have to add these scripts to this file `sudo gedit /etc/modules` which i did but still didn't work.

[image: screenshoot of adding the code to modules]
I'm new to ubuntu and i'm really liking it. I can get my second screen set.

TIA!

Comment: Or: http://askubuntu.com/questions/609490/running-a-script-at-startup-that-uses-xrandr-to-set-display-options/609499#609499, or: http://askubuntu.com/questions/582752/permanently-set-the-resolution-for-my-second-monitor/582762#582762

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/modules` file is for kernel moludes ( aka drivers). It says right at the top of the file. That's not the right place to put custom commands.

**Step 1**: Take those 3 commands, save in a `set-screen.sh` somewhere in your home directory. For example, mine would be in `/home/serg/bin/set-screen.sh` and that's how it would look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 15
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 1368x768_60.00
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode  1368x768_60.00
```

**Step 2**: do in terminal `chmod 755 set-screen.sh`.

**Step 3**: Open the `Startup Applications` and add full path to your file as one of the startup commands.

**Note**: alternatively you could add `/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && /home/serg/bin/set-screen.sh"` as command to Startup Applications, and remove `sleep 15` entry from the script itself

Now every time you log in, those 3 commands will run automatically 15 seconds right after you log in. Note, that these commands won't run until you log in, so the log-in screen will be with the old resolution

Comment: Without a small break before the script runs, in many cases the script breaks (due to `xrandr` commands) or misses its target, especially when using external screens.

Comment: @JacobVlijm so . . .should I add `sleep 3` to the beginning ?

Comment: I think 3 is too little, I would say somewhere between 15 and 50, depending on the system. or make the xrandr test smart somehow :)

Comment: ...Or add the sleep to the startup command: `/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && /home/serg/bin/set-screen.sh"

Comment: @JacobVlijm Edited my answer to include the suggestions :)

Comment: @BryanGumpic the question was a dupe, but there is nothing against accepting the answer still :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the xorg.conf

It's the best way to set the resolution for your second monitor:

Login use xrandr to change everything, so that the second monitor has the right resolution and then open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo Xorg :1 -configure
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf_bak
sudo cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

(Do not forget to always backup your config files, if the second command fails because the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf doesn't exists, ignore it.)

See [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_xorg.conf) for more details.